# How To Use MongoDB Aggregate

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have the following data object:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "56bab”,
    "region": “AS”,
    “spentOn”: [
      “56bf623a0c90b5”
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "57bab",
    "region": "EU",
    "spentOn": [
      "b5”,
      "b6”,
      "b8”,
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "58bab",
    "region": "EU",
    "spentOn": [
      "b5”
      "b6”
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to write a MongoDB call (from JS) to get the most common `spentOn` value based on a region i specify.
For example, if i say region='EU' I would expect to get back: b6, b5 and b8.

I've read on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23402593/most-common-distinct-values-mongodb) and attempted the below, however not sure how i get the ones for a particular region?

```
return Q.promise(function(resolve, reject) {
   User.aggregate( [
        { $group: { _id: "$spentOn", count: { "$sum":1 } } },
        { }
    ] );
    resolve();
});
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I think you might be misrepresenting context a little here. Rather than "object", don't you mean that these are all "objects" in your `User` "collection"? Also, what do you think the `{}` as the second pipeline stage is meant to do? + Big hint is reading documentation. i.e [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/). And this is all covered by reading all of [Aggregation Examples](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/) in the core documentation.

Comment: Oh and also. The modern MongoDB node driver implementation ( current version ) as well as ["mongoose"](http://mongoosejs.com/) ( that you "appear" to be using at a glance ) all support Promises natively. So no need to wrap in a Promise. Most things you "read on the web" are generally out of date, with regard to such things. Read the driver and library docs instead of blog posts.

Comment: @BlakesSeven thanks for that info. Will read into unwind now. And regarding the promises I'm having to use as there are several steps that I didnt show in this example so I use Q.all() in a later stage of my code. I tried using native promises (using `then` once a result is found but that didnt work).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like it has already been suggested in the comments, the trick here is to use the [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) stage.

So, a possible solution for this can be:

```
db.users.aggregate([
    {$match:{
        region: "EU"    
    }},
    {$unwind:"$spentOn"},
    {$group:{
        _id: "$spentOn",
        count: {$sum:1}
    }},
    {$sort: {count:-1}}
])
```

Which gives the following result:

```
{ "_id" : "b6", "count" : 2 }
{ "_id" : "b5", "count" : 2 }
{ "_id" : "b8", "count" : 1 }
```

Comment: That was it - I missed the match and unwind. Many Thanks!