# get $max of string

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to aggregate data on my mongodb and to get some statistics regarding a collection,
i have a field called country and i need to get the one that exists the most
below attached is the current code,

consider my collection has 3 document:

```
{_id:1, country:"Italy"}
{_id:1, country:"Zimbabwe"}
{_id:1, country:"Italy"}
```

The expected output should be :Italy
But in reality i get Zimbabwe because it compares Z > I

```
visitSchema.statics.calcTotalVisits = async function (link) {
  const stats = await this.aggregate([
    {
      $match: { link },
    },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: '$link',
        sumDocs: { $sum: 1 },
        topReferer: { $max: '$referer' },
        topCountry: { $max: '$country' },
      },
    },
  ]);
  console.log(stats);
};
```

Comment: `_id` should always be unique.

Comment: Does this answer your question? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23402593/most-common-distinct-values-mongodb/23402791

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Most common distinct values mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23402593/most-common-distinct-values-mongodb)